# How to organise/layout large number of controls?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

I've been playing around with the auto-layout feature of XCode 6 in developing a Swift application for the iPhone.

It works well for a small number of controls but I now find myself with a section on the screen which will consist of a matrix of eight by eight small text controls (in portrait mode) of the form `7☐` and `42☑` (all three characters), each which can be selected by the user (toggling the checkbox).

I'm wondering what's the best way to handle this. I started by simply laying out all sixty-four text controls but this quickly became a nightmare in trying to join them all together with constraints.

I then wondered whether it would be easier to have *one* text control in a fixed-width font (or in a font where all digits are the same width and a space character of that width is also available) so I could control the layout manually (with newlines). The downside of that is that I'll then need to perform hit-testing on the control to see which item should be toggled.

Both these approaches have the downside that they don't adjust well when switching to landscape mode or to other resolution changes.

So my question is, how do I handle this in a way that can take full advantage of auto layout (i.e., minimal work for the developer). Ideally what I'm looking for is something like the Java Swing `FlowLayout` container, to which I can just insert those text controls in order, and it will fill it out as if it's a book (populate top line, left to right, then next line and so on).

Comment: If you have a matrix like layout, you can/should use a UICollectionView, I think that matches the best what you are trying to achive.

Comment: @Dániel, I'm just going through a tutorial and it looks pretty good. You should make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix like layout and you want it to flow like the `FlowLayout` from Swing, you can use a `UICollectionView`.

I think that matches best what you are trying to achieve.